# How to make main window inactive after error JFrame pops

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

So I have a main frame that sometimes produces an error frame by pressing on one of the JButtons. I want to make it so when the error frame pops, main frame is inactive and you are unable to press any buttons. Is there an easy way for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are referring to is modality<sup>1</sup>, for which case a modal `JDialog` is more appropriate than a `JFrame`. See more at [How to Use Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Also, if this is a simple message popup, a simple `JOptionPane` would be more suitable. You can also see how to use `JOptionPanes` in the link above.

Here's a simple `JOPtionPane` example. Though I don't use a frame in the example, if you *do* have a frame, the `JOptionPane` will block any user interaction.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class SimpleErrorMessage {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
               null, "Error!", "Error Message", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }  
}
```

[image]

- See [`JOptionPane` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) for more dialog options.

<sub>1. A dialog box can be either modeless or modal. A modal dialog box is one that blocks input to some other top-level windows in the application, except for any windows created with the dialog box as their owner. The modal dialog box captures the window focus until it is closed, usually in response to a button press</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You can use a glass pane to make main frame "inactive": http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html